# Redis Node - Get from hash - Not inserting into array

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

My goal is to insert the values gotten from a redis hash. I am using the redis package for node js.

My code is the following:

```
getFromHash(ids) {
    const resultArray = [];
    ids.forEach((id) => {
      common.redisMaster.hget('mykey', id, (err, res) => {
        resultArray.push(res);
      });
    });
    console.log(resultArray);
  },
```

The array logged at the end of the function is empty and res is not empty. What could i do to fill this array please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your code to something like this, it will work nicely:

```
var getFromHash = function getFromHash(ids) {
    const resultArray = [];
    ids.forEach((id) => {
        common.redisMaster.hget('mykey', id, (err, res) => {
            resultArray.push(res);
            if (resultArray.length === ids.length) {
                // All done.
                console.log('getFromHash complete: ', resultArray);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

In your original code you're printing the result array before any of the hget calls have returned.

Another approach will be to create an array of promises and then do a Promise.all on it.

You'll see this kind of behavior a lot with Node, remember it uses asynchronous calls for almost all i/o. When you're coming from a language where most function calls are synchronous you get tripped up by this kind of problem a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some control flow, either the [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library or Promises ([as described in reds docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#promises))

Put your `console.log` inside the callback when the results return from the redis call. Then you will see more print out. Use one of the control flow patterns for your `.forEach` as well, as that is currently synchronous.